# Content translation not working on the front page

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n, 9

I have a translation problem on my site in drupal 9.1.3.

I have a content type for my homepage that contains two fields: field_slides which is an EntiyReferenceRevisionFieldItemList to a Paragraphs field and field_tabulations which is an EntityReferenceFieldItemList to a "tab" content type.

This type of content contains 4 fields including a Paragraphs field.

My configuration in admin / config / regional / content-language is correct. And I only enabled translation for child paragraphs fields as said in the documentation.

In the template I call the title field of the entity referenced by field_tabulations as follows:

```
{{ elements['field_tabulations']['# items'].0.entity.title.0.value }}
```

However, the home page node fields in my template front page are not translated. The blocks are, however as the main menu is.

Comment: "Cross-entity rendering" (e.g. something like `{{ some_entity.some_field.0.entity.whatever }}`) in templates is neither cache-safe nor language-safe. Anything behind a `.entity` should be considered outside the scope of the current template. Better use the proper paragraph and field templates instead.

Comment: Many thanks @Hudri! I can't figure out how to get a field not passing through the entity.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't pass field values between templates, but render them in parent with `{{ content.field_foo }}` and in the child template do the proper formatting.

Comment: yes. But in this case the field is only available on the entity afaik. I will look forward. Many thanks